# LINQ to XML returns no result

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am using Linq to to parse an XML, but it return no result:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <downloadInfoResponse xmlns="http://webService">
                <downloadInfoReturn>
                <city>city</city>
                <companyName>company name</companyName>
            </downloadInfoReturn>
        </downloadInfoResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Code:

```
public class Merc
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(result)))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
    List<Merc> m = (from downloadInfoReturn in doc.Descendants("downloadInfoReturn")
                    select new Merc
                    {
                        CompanyName = downloadMerchantInfoReturn.Element("companyName").Value
                    }).ToList();
}
```

Is there any other good method to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Note: You're doing `new Merchant` but your class is called `Merc`. Makes it easier to find and test a problem if it can actually run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your XML file contains namespaces thus you need to specify it when perform querying:

```
XNamespace xn = "http://webService";
doc.Descendants(xn + "downloadInfoReturn")
```

Comment: Thank you. got a new error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @KelvinFixx: In what line do you get it?

Comment: @KelvinFixx: Break the code into multiple lines. And you will see. What type of the exception? Is it `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Solved add xn to this statement CompanyName = downloadMerchantInfoReturn.Element(xn + "companyName").Value

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing the namespace while querying the xml, also your class name doesn't match, try the following code, it works on my side.

```
 List<Merc> m = null;
 XNamespace ns = "http://webService";
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(result)))
      {
         XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
         m = (from downloadInfoReturn in doc.Descendants(ns + "downloadInfoReturn")
                   select new Merc
                       {
                         CompanyName = downloadInfoReturn.Element(ns+ "companyName").Value
                        }).ToList<Merc>();
            }
    Console.WriteLine(m.Count); // this will show 1
```

Comment: I've downvoted because there's no explanation of what this actually does. The same goes for Ivan in the other question.

Comment: He does give me a clue to answer my question. Thank you Habib.

Comment: @Habib It's correct and I'm sure it helps, but you don't say anywhere what your changes do.

Comment: @Tharwen, I have update my answer, I thought the issue of missing namespace was obvious, but I have added the explanation  as well.

Comment: It's not obvious, because then there would be no need for the question in the first place. Anyway, you can have your vote back now.